# Best way to store and serve static content in bulk

Tags: django, caching, nginx, varnish, django-flatpages

I have an application that generates static pages. say roughly around 10 html pages/min. These pages are going to be served to users. On server side, I am using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) as development framework with [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) to run my App server and I am using [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) as 'Reverse Proxy'.

With this stack, I have few doubts regarding my design for **Storing and Serving content**. Also I am not sure, If my approach will cause any performance penalty which I am not able to guess now. So here are my thoughts on this:

### Storage

I am thinking of a flat file based system to store content. Which will be stored according to timestamp so that I can clear/delete them up in future In case content is expired or it's not required. So path for a typical file will look like `/var/www/project/content/timestamp/file/path`.

I also checked Django [Flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) (app available in Django) which allows easy maintains of flatpages using admin panel and API. But this looks more promising for,

- Fixed number of pages and       `(for me, it's huge and varying)`
- If you have any Editing requirement for the pages. `(I don't need this)`

### Serving

For serving the content I am planing of exposing the '/var/www/content/' folder by **Nginx** so that it can be directly served by Nginx without any delay from app server.
In case, I see any performance hit. I can use some static file caching Engine like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

Any suggestion or thought will be helpful. Thanks..

Comment: Use CDN or S3 to serve the static content.use style.css?version=1 style of urls to serve the newer versions of static files.

Comment: @Darklord: Thanks for reply. As I commented on the answer below. In my case, I can't take advantage of CDN. Also once the content is generated it's not modified again so I am not worried about versioning.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably offload the responsibility of storing these static files to S3, and serve them via CloudFront.

Comment: Hi Brandon, My content doesn't really take advantage of CDN. Most of the content is such that. It is served to people in fixed geographical location and a user does NOT access multiple content resource together. Besides this cost is my other important concern. Hence looking for a near optimal soluton that I can build.

Comment: Regardless of geographic area, you're going to be hard pressed to build a more scalable system that Amazon. I leverage S3/CloudFront for several freelance clients with high static content needs, and my bills are typically pennies a month.

Comment: Hmm, Thanks I can probably give it a try.

Comment: I don't think you'll be disappointed. Check out django-storages: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. It makes pushing content to S3 via an Image/FileField ridiculously easy.